Bluetooth speaker as headset instead of speaker
I have a UE boom 2 bluetooth speaker, that can be also used as a headset/handsfree call system.
Before, when I used to connect the speaker to the computer, the sound was very good as it was picking it as speaker but since couple of weeks, it recognise it only as a headset and thus produce a very pour sound instead of a proper speaker.
Settings are very pour as I can only select or not the device. I tried to install Pavucontrol, but it does not help a lot.
Is there a way to include something la pavu control directly inside the settings, and give the option to use the bluetooth speaker either as handsfree system or as a speaker ?
Kind regards
